# Matching only non-numeric elements

Tags: regex

I am trying to search only non-numeric elements from a string like

```
info,25892,25696,26421,26513,13486,26976,27588,26000,22840,bla,aby3
```

using Regular expression. I have tried and this way I can find only words

```
 `[^\d,]+ `
```

but `alphanumerics`  I can't

Comment: What do you want to find???? You exclude digits and want alphanumerics? Maybe an example would be good.

Comment: I want to delete all the alpha-numeric words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using PHP You can easly achive this w/o using regular expressions at all, just run:

```
$string = '1234,45,67f,a67a,434334,3fd';
$foo = explode(',', $string);
$foo = array_filter($foo, 'is_numeric');
var_dump($foo);
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding regex when it's not necessary. Bonus points for `array_filter()`.